# How to update the DOM in angular 4 after updating global style.css file?

Tags: angular

In my project once the project gets bootstrap's style.css rules gets attached into style tag inside the head tag of index.html file. What i am doing is once the project gets bootstrapped i am changing the some css rule properties programatically using node.js. But, updated css properties not getting applied in DOM. Please help me to find a way for this .

Answer (score 1):

Well, the global styles are loaded once and if you have an update on the style css you should refresh the page.

But updating the global css is not a good practice. Angular provides you easily manipulation of your DOM with typescript.

Plz refer this link [Angular4 - changing css class dynamically - which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094785/angular4-changing-css-class-dynamically-which-is-better)

---

Here is a github issue with the same question like you have
https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/1457

Comment: Any possibility that could help me in refreshing the page. But, without using window.location.reload(); which i have already tried.

Comment: is it possible to use gulp-livereload for change detection in angular 4 application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448422/gulp-js-with-live-reload-what-gets-reloaded